# How can I skip back a few seconds after pause in VLC Media Player?

Tags: vlc

I've searched this on the internet, but can't seem to find anything. I know there are hotkeys to skip back a few seconds, and I know there are hotkeys to to pause and play audio/video in VLC Media Player. However, I am using a single foot pedal for transcription and essentially need it to do both. I would like the pedal tap to pause the audio. Then, after tapping again, I would like it to play the audio, but skipping a few seconds back when doing so. Is this possible?

Comment: Add a language tag like `C++` or `C#`, also show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Are you sure this is a programming question? Might it be better suited to anohter stackexchange forum?

Comment: Oh, I think you're right. Not sure where I was supposed to post it... Sorry, guys!

Comment: Perhaps [superuser](https://superuser.com/) see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257902/where-to-ask-questions-on-vlc-media-player).

Comment: you should be able to do this with a simple VLC lua script, I could write up some code if you're still interested

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem. @Ryan did you solve it?

Comment: @Tee I'm stuck with the same problem, any help?

Comment: sure i'll post an answer soon

Comment: And for linux ?

Answer (score 1):

Save this code as `rollback.lua` and place it in `Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\extensions` folder. Then activate it through View > Rollback X Seconds.

```
function descriptor()
   return {
      title = "Rollback X Seconds",
      capabilities = {"input-listener", "playing-listener"}
   }
end

function activate()
end
function close()
end
function deactivate()
end

function input_changed()
end

function playing_changed()
    local TIME_DELTA = -3

    if vlc.playlist.status()=="paused" then

        local timePassed = vlc.var.get(vlc.object.input(), "time")
        local newTime = timePassed + TIME_DELTA

        vlc.osd.message(TIME_DELTA, vlc.osd.channel_register(), "top-left", 1400000)        
        vlc.var.set(vlc.object.input(), "time", newTime)
    end
end
```

Change the variable `TIME_DELTA` to whatever time change you want on pause

Comment: Tried that, did not work (the script is enabled but does nothing).
Also it is unclear in what units the time is (seconds? miliseconds?), but I tried setting times ranging from -1 to -10000 and still there was no effect.

Comment: Me too, only `activate()` gets called.

Answer (score 1):

I expanded on the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44014632/how-can-i-skip-back-a-few-seconds-after-pause-in-vlc-media-player/53143784#53143784) provided by [Tee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5212252/tee) by adding a GUI.
I would also like to add a few details of how to get it working.

1. Create a empty file, name it rollback.lua.
2. Copy the code provided underneath this list, paste into the file and save.
3. Move the file to VLCs folder for lua extensions, it should look something like this:
     c:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/lua/extensions
4. Restart VLC player.
5. Activate the script by going to (**Note! Needs to be done each time you start VLC to use the plugin**)
   view > Rollback X Seconds
6. Select time in seconds you want to rollback and hit save (or save and close).

In order to get your pedal working with this script, simply configure the hotkey in VLC for play/pause toggle.
VLC >  Tools > Preferences > Hotkeys > Set "Play/Pause" Global value to be your pedal.
*(After you change a Global hotkey, you need to restart VLC in order to get it working...)*

The code:

```
micro_second_unit = 1000000  
TIME_DELTA        = 1     --Default, 
SHOW_OUTPUT       = true
TIME_TO_DISPLAY   = 1.5    --Default


function descriptor()
   return {
      title = "Rollback X Seconds",
      capabilities = {"input-listener", "playing-listener"}
   }
end

function activate()
    dlg = vlc.dialog("Rollback X Seconds")    

    rollback_input         = dlg:add_text_input("1", 2, 1 )    
    rollback_input_label   = dlg:add_label("Seconds to back", 1, 1)

    checkBox = dlg:add_check_box("Show output time ", wasChecked, 3, 3 )

    timeTo_display_box        = dlg:add_text_input(1.5, 2 ,3)
    timeTo_display_box_label  = dlg:add_label("Seconds To Display", 1, 3)

    w2 = dlg:add_button("Save settings", change_step, 3, 4, 1, 1)
    w2 = dlg:add_button("Save and close", updateAndClose, 3, 5, 1, 1)

    done = dlg:add_label( "" , 3, 6)

end
function close()
end
function deactivate()
   vlc.deactivate()
end

function input_changed()
end

function playing_changed()    

    if vlc.playlist.status()=="paused" then

        local timePassed = tonumber(vlc.var.get(vlc.object.input(), "time"))
        local newTime = timePassed - seconds_to_microsecond(TIME_DELTA)

        local newTime_inSeconds     = (newTime/1000000)
        local newTime_inMinutes     = (newTime_inSeconds/60)
        local newTime_inSeconds_restOfMin  = math.fmod(newTime_inSeconds,60)
        local newTime_str           = math.floor(newTime_inMinutes) .. "min " .. round(newTime_inSeconds_restOfMin,1) .."sec"        

        local timePassed_inSeconds  = (timePassed/1000000)
        local timePassed_inMinutes  = (timePassed_inSeconds/60)
        local timePassed_inSeconds_restOfMin  = math.fmod(timePassed_inSeconds,60)

        local timePassed_str  = math.floor(timePassed_inMinutes) .. "min " .. round(timePassed_inSeconds_restOfMin,1) .."sec"


        if SHOW_OUTPUT == true then
            vlc.osd.message("Seconds to Back:" .. TIME_DELTA .. "sec", vlc.osd.channel_register(), "top-right", seconds_to_microsecond(TIME_TO_DISPLAY))  

           vlc.osd.message("New time:" .. newTime_str, vlc.osd.channel_register(), "top-left", seconds_to_microsecond(TIME_TO_DISPLAY))   

           vlc.osd.message("Old time:" .. timePassed_str, vlc.osd.channel_register(), "bottom-left", seconds_to_microsecond(TIME_TO_DISPLAY))   
        end


        vlc.var.set(vlc.object.input(), "time", newTime)
    end
end
function updateAndClose()
   change_step()
   dlg:delete()
end

function change_step()
    done:set_text("Saved")

   TIME_DELTA = tonumber(rollback_input:get_text())

   SHOW_OUTPUT = checkBox:get_checked()

   if SHOW_OUTPUT == true then 
      TIME_TO_DISPLAY = tonumber(timeTo_display_box:get_text())
   end 

end

function round(num, numDecimalPlaces)
  local mult = 10^(numDecimalPlaces or 0)
  return math.floor(num * mult + 0.5) / mult
end

function microsecond_to_seconds(timeToConvert)  

  return timeToConvert / micro_second_unit;
end

function seconds_to_microsecond(timeToConvert)

  return timeToConvert * micro_second_unit;
end
```

This will work just like Tee's script, the video will jump back each time it's paused.
Only difference is that you can set the amount of time to jump back each time you start the script.
The amount is given in seconds, however you can use decimals for more control...
*There's also a checkbox you can tick if you want to display information about the jump*.

I also want to thank Tee for his answer!
This is the first lua code I've written (*or rather, modified*) and it's a bit messy, but it works and I have used it every day since so I thought I might as well share it.

Comment: For those of you scratching your head about the menu part in Mac OS X VLC 3.0, it's under `VLC -> Extensions -> Rollback X Seconds`

Comment: Installed this, it shows up and I can configure it, but it does nothing. VLC 3.0.12 on macOS 11.2.1